# Should the bugs requests tagged "status-norepro" be removed from the bug specific view?

Tags: discussion, bugs-reqs-tabs

The [bugs tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=bugs) is a good place to see the most "active" bugs. However, if "status completed" is taking the bug away from this view, understandably, "status norepro" doesn't remove it.

In a way, if a bug is local, and can't be reproduced by the team, shouldn't it be taken away from this list?

Answer (score 2):

What happens if it gets reproduced later, by someone other than the team and the originator?  We'll have a ton of duplicate, hard-to-reproduce bug requests because no one saw them the first time.

Comment: Question can be updated, or put to front with a new answer. The tag can be taken away then by a member of the team, and it would come back to the list, I think.

Comment: Duplicate irreproducible bug reports didn't seem to plague Meta that badly back before we had the Bugs tab.

Comment: I agree -- sometimes this tag gets added a little too zealously and there is a repro case, but perhaps not documented very well.  If the post really truly is irrelevant, it should be closed, which should remove it from the list.